# Linear solenoid mount

Tags: electromagnetism, linear-motion

I have a linear solenoid with a tapped M3 hole at the end of the plunger, like this:

[image: Linear solenoid with tapped M3 hole in plunger]

I need to connect this plunger to a lever, so I want to add a mount which has a connection something like this:

[image: Linear solenoid with desired mount on plunger]

Does anyone have any suggestions as to where I could find an M3 mount like this which I could attach to my solenoid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. An image search for "M3 clevis male" throws up a wheelbarrow-full of images.*

You could use a female thread version but would need to connect the them with a male stud and maybe some thread locking compound.